# Plotting multiple lines with same color, but using hue to separate the lines

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have this data, and I want to plot a line for Age vs Predicted Probability for each Obs.

```
Age    Predicted Probability  Obs
18.0   0.206                  3.0
15.0   0.206                  3.0
34.0   0.154                  3.0
52.0   0.124                  3.0
46.0   0.146                  3.0
18.0   0.000                  2.0
15.0   0.000                  2.0
34.0   0.000                  2.0
52.0   0.098                  2.0
46.0   0.002                  2.0
18.0   0.000                  1.0
15.0   0.000                  1.0
34.0   0.004                  1.0
52.0   0.078                  1.0
46.0   0.006                  1.0
18.0   0.038                  0.0
15.0   0.032                  0.0
34.0   0.384                  0.0
52.0   0.318                  0.0
46.0   0.348                  0.0
```

I did this through the following code in seaborn:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Age", y="Predicted Probability", hue = 'Obs')
```

Using the hue argument. But I don't want a different color for each line. In fact I want a black line for each Obs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `hue` is set, seaborn wants to draw each line in a different color. These colors are chosen from the palette (in this case the default palette has 10 different colors).

You can create a custom palette, e.g. from a list of colors. Even a list with just one element. So, `palette = sns.color_palette(['black'])`.

An annoyance is that seaborn insists that the palette has exactly the same number of colors as there are hue-values. Therefore, that number needs to be provided as a parameter (`palette = sns.color_palette(['black'], number_of_colors)`).

Here is some example code (the default legend has been turned off, as all lines now have the same color):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''Age    "Predicted Probability"  Obs
18.0   0.206                  3.0
15.0   0.206                  3.0
34.0   0.154                  3.0
52.0   0.124                  3.0
46.0   0.146                  3.0
18.0   0.000                  2.0
15.0   0.000                  2.0
34.0   0.000                  2.0
52.0   0.098                  2.0
46.0   0.002                  2.0
18.0   0.000                  1.0
15.0   0.000                  1.0
34.0   0.004                  1.0
52.0   0.078                  1.0
46.0   0.006                  1.0
18.0   0.038                  0.0
15.0   0.032                  0.0
34.0   0.384                  0.0
52.0   0.318                  0.0
46.0   0.348                  0.0
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)

palette = sns.color_palette(['black'], len(df['Obs'].unique()))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Age", y="Predicted Probability", hue='Obs', palette=palette, legend=False)
```

[image: sns.lineplot only using black]

PS: An alternative that doesn't need counting nor manually separating the hues, is creating a `ListedColormap` with one color:

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Age", y="Predicted Probability", hue='Obs', palette=ListedColormap(['black']), legend=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the appearance of lines by **hue** or **dashes**

1. hue colors depend on color_palette

---

you can use `seaborn.set_palette` before drawing to set custom or any  palette predefined  that can be used when you draw different data on same plot . [can see more examples and info from seaborn doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_palette.html)
you  may find preferred colors in documentation or can define your palette
[seaborn.color_palette object used to pass to set_palette](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html).

```
# Create an array with the colors you want to use
colors = ["#FF0B04", "#4374B3"]# Set your custom color palette

sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))
#plot anything with hue ...first color takes category and so on 
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="Age", y="Predicted Probability", hue = 'Obs')
```

you can this helpful also [How to use your own color palettes with Seaborn  by Carolina Bento Aug 22, 2019·3 min read](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-your-own-color-palettes-with-seaborn-a45bf5175146)

2. you can use dashes also

---

Also you can try this **dashes** property inside lineplot function if you don't like using **hue** :

> dashes: boolean, list, or dictionary

> Object determining how to draw the lines for different levels of the
> style variable. Setting to True will use default dash codes, or you
> can pass a list of dash codes or a dictionary mapping levels of the
> style variable to dash codes. Setting to False will use solid lines
> for all subsets. Dashes are specified as in matplotlib: a tuple of
> (segment, gap) lengths, or an empty string to draw a solid line.

```
sns.lineplot(x="Age", y="Predicted Probability",style='Obs',dashes=[(1,1),(5, 10)],data=df)
```

[this article can help you revise most of lineplot properties](https://www.marsja.se/seaborn-line-plots-multiple/)