# In seaborn, how can I group by a variable without using the "hue" argument?

Tags: python, seaborn

In seaborn, is it possible to group observations based on a column *without using the `hue` argument?*

For example, how could I get these two lines to show up in the same colour, but as separate lines?

[image]

Code for generating this is below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group': ["group01", "group01", "group02", "group02"],
        'x': [1, 2, 3, 5],
        'y': [2, 4, 3, 5]
    }
)
sns.lineplot(df, x='x', y='y', hue='group')
plt.show()
```

This is straightforward to do in R's ggplot, by mapping the group variable to `group`, rather than to `colour`. For example, see [this](https://bookdown.dongzhuoer.com/hadley/ggplot2-book/multiple-groups-one-aesthetic.html).

The reason I want to do this is that I want to show multiple overlaid plots all in the same colour. This helps to show variability across different datasets. The different colours that I would get with seaborn's `hue` are unnecessary and distracting, especially when there would be dozens of them. Here is the sort of plot I want to create:

[image]

Comment: Does this help for seaborn [Plotting multiple lines with same color, but using hue to separate the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221399/plotting-multiple-lines-with-same-color-but-using-hue-to-separate-the-lines) Alternately, since Python also has R's ggplot2 you could use it i.e. [A Grammar of Graphics for Python](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for! Also, I am aware of `plotnine`, but was just curious about the best way to handle it in `seaborn`.

Comment: I will also add that plotnine has a ways to go to produce polished figured. If you do something like rotate the colorbar legend title or other similar twicks things always get misaligned and are hard (if even possible) to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) has a `units` parameter, which seems to be equivalent to ggplot's `group`:

> **units**:  vector or key in data
>
> Grouping variable identifying sampling units. When used, a separate line will be drawn for each unit with appropriate semantics,
> but no legend entry will be added. Useful for showing distribution of
> experimental replicates when exact identities are not needed.

```
sns.lineplot(df, x='x', y='y', units='group')
```

Output:

[image]

combining `units` and `hue` in a more complex example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group': ["group01", "group01", "group02", "group02", "group01", "group01"],
        'group2': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'x': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4],
        'y': [2, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2]
    }
)
sns.lineplot(df, x='x', y='y', units='group', hue='group2')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This does answer the question perfectly, so I'll accept it as the answer. One suggestion, though: maybe mention that not all `seaborn` functions have the `units` argument. E.g. `sns.distplot` does not. In that case, I think the solution that @DarrylG
mentioned in a comment is probably the best.

Comment: @Nayef other functions have it (like `pointplot`), but I don't know the exhaustive list. I am not sure if this would apply to a function that does not have the parameter, do you have an example in mind?